# How to detect which dynamically created button inside a Fragment was clicked, from Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment class that dynamically creates a grid of Buttons. An instance of that fragment is then created within the main activity which displays the grid. Here is my code:

Grid.java

```
public class Grid extends Fragment {

    LinearLayout myLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        myLayout.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        myLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            LayoutParams rowParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                final Button btnTag = new Button(getActivity());
                LayoutParams btnParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                btnTag.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
                btnTag.setText(" " + (j + 1 + (i * 4)));
                btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
                row.addView(btnTag);
            }

            myLayout.addView(row);
        }
        return myLayout;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_mainactivity);
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.grid, grid);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And in addition here is my content_mainactivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_mainactivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.owner.tables.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_mainactivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So my question is, how can I detect if and which button was clicked in fragment from the Activity? Or if I can do this in the fragment, how to pass on the information to the activity?

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface to pass the click event to your activity. Call its method inside the OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity

```
public void doSomethingAtClick() {...}
```

In fragment

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).doSomethingAtClick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface:

```
public interface MyGridInterface  {
    void myAction(<Params...>);
}
```

Set Listener in Fragment:

```
MainActivity mActivity = new MainActivity();
setEleListener(mActivity);

public void setMyListener(MyGridInterface listener) {
        this.gListener = listener;
    }
```

Implement the Listener in MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyGridInterface{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_mainactivity);
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.grid, grid);
        transaction.commit();
    }


  @Override
    public void myAction(<Params..>) {

        //Here do whatever you want
    }

}
```

Comment: I am confused about setEleListener does? Is this a method that needs to be implemented in the Fragment or does it already belong to the Fragment object? Further more does the fragment need to have a field of the form "MyGridInterface gListener;"?

Comment: Just set listener to the MainActivity to listen events from fragment to activity